# How to check if a dictionary of a certain key contain a value?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

So if I have a dictionary, for which each key can take more that one values (i.e `Dictionary < string , Hashset < string >>`) and now I want to check if dic [key a] contain a value for example "b" in the hashset of dic[a]? How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think the most efficient way of testing the existence  is if the structure and check function are defined like this:

```
// extension method on IDictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> can be used
public static bool ContainsKeyValue<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> dictOfHash, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (!dictOfHash.ContainsKey(key))
        return false;

    return dictOfHash[key].Contains(value);
}

var dict = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<String>>()
{
    { 1, new HashSet<String>() { "one", "two", "three"} },
    { 2, new HashSet<String>() { "ten", "eleven", "twelve"} } 
};

bool exists = ContainsKeyValue(dict, 1, "two");
exists = ContainsKeyValue(dict, 1, null);
exists = ContainsKeyValue(dict, 2, "one");
exists = ContainsKeyValue(dict, 3, null);
```

Existence check should have a complexity of O(1), as both `Dictionary<,>` and `Hashset<>` have a get/set complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extension method

```
public static bool Contains<Tkey, TValue>(this Dictionary<Tkey, IEnumerable<TValue>> dic, Tkey key, TValue val)
{
    if (dic.ContainsKey(key))
        return dic[key].Contains(val);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think i forgot to add, that it searches for this string b in the hashset of dic[a]. This code will throw an error as my value is a string not a hashset of strings.

Comment: I can not understand you, Can you reformulate your sentence?

Comment: No, I'm sorry it worked. I didn't see the "enumerable" at first glance. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as the solution to your problem if it was your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try out  `IDictionary<>.TryGetValue` which saves one table lookup:

```
public static bool Contains<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    var hashSet; 
    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out hashSet))
    {
       return hashSet.Contains(value);
    } 
    else 
    {
          return false;
    }         
}
```